# Use umlauts in UTF-8 coded HTML-files with firefox

Tags: html, firefox, utf-8, opera

```
<h1>Wörterbuch</h1>
```

This is a very simple (generated by *Zotero*) html file and it is UTF-8 coded.
But *firefox* is not able to handle it correct.

When viewing the source of the opened html file in *firefox* it looks like that.

```
<h1>WÃ¶rterbuch</h1>
```

My last touch of HTML is from the beginning of the 90's. This file is UTF-8 so firefox should know itself how to handle the `ö` their. But it doesn't so I need something in the header, right?
What information does firefox need here?

This work well with *Opera*.

Comment: You really should use `<meta charset="utf-8">` or HTTP header with same meaning.

Comment: There is no 100%-reliable way to distinguish UTF-8 and Windows-1252/ISO 8859-1/\latin-1

Comment: @AlexeyTen: Every browser supports `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` at the HTTP layer, or in an HTML4 `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" value="text/html; charset=utf-8">` tag in the HTML.  Every HTML5 browser supports a `<meta charset="utf-8">` tag in the HTML. What's the problem?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, the problem is than PA did not use any of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure your HTTP server is sending the correct HTTP header to identify the encoding of the document:

   ```
   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
   ```
2. As a fallback, add the `<meta>` tag to the document's `<head>`:

   ```
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   ```

Comment: Note that `<meta charset="utf-8">` is for HTML5 only. For HTML4, you can use `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" value="text/html; charset=utf-8">` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, there is no reason to use HTML4. And, BTW short meta will work even in ie6 see http://stackoverflow.com/a/20362650/1016033